# Cutting sink boss from granite composite sink

Tags: cutting, kitchen-sink, granite

We have a Swanstone composite granite drop in sink. We have a very narrow counter. The sink fits but the sink boss extensions in the front will not be used and I would really like to cut them off to gain the extra half inch plus in the back so we can position the sink out from under a window sill and I can install a tall faucet. 
Just don't know if I can just saw them off or if there are considerations for safety and durability that I need to consider. Also what would be the best tool to use for this? 
Thank you for your input.

Comment: Can you post a picture or reference to the sink? Chances are, you could just hack them off with an angle grinder, but this carries considerable risk.

Comment: "the boss extensions in the front" - what, exactly, do you mean, here - the rim/flange of the sink? That's definitely structural. I can't find anything referred to as a "boss extension" in the installation manual https://swanstone.com/images/link_installation/Drop-In%20KS%20Installation%20Instructions.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the tabs for the brackets to attach?, cut them off with a 4" diamond cutting blade; have eye protection and shop vac hose tied off near cut to cut down dust; hold up on very slight angle to avoid cutting into rim edge of sink top. Silicone that edge down with some weight on top until silicone sets up.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.